# One to many relationship in Parse(js) and nested queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm having trouble creating a one-to-many relationship in Parse(js) and querying the results.

I have a Restaurant Table and a Menu Table. A restaurant can have many menu items and they are defined as such:

**Restaurant Table**
restaurant_name(string)
address(string)

**Menu Table**
menu_item_name(string)
restaurant(pointer to Restaurant Table)

How would I go about displaying all the restaurants and there respective menu items?

Right now I'm displaying this is console.log(), but I'm not sure how to do thi. Below is the code that I was working with.

```
  <script>
  function getRestaurants(){
    Parse.initialize("...", "...");      
    var Restaurant = Parse.Object.extend("Restaurant");
    var Menu = Parse.Object.extend("Menu");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Restaurant);
      query.find({
        success:function(results){
          for(var i in results){
            //second loop- for menu items
            var query2 = new Parse.Query(Menu);
            query2.include("restaurant");
            query2.find({
              success:function(results2){ 
                for(var j in results2){

                  if(results[i] == results2[j].get("restaurant");){
                    //display restaurant name and all menu items

                  }

                }
              }, error: function(error){
                console.log("Query Error"+error.message);
              }
            });
          }
        }, 
        error: function(error){
          console.log("Query Error"+error.message);
        }
      });
    }
    getRestaurants();
  </script>
```

**Edit 1**
As a proof of concept, I would like to display this on the console - Note: this example assumes there are 3 restaurants in the table and each contains 2 menu items. This wont always be the case; the number of restaurants and number of menu items aren't static:

Restaurant name 1
- Menu item name 1
- Menu item name 2

Restaurant name 2
- Menu item name 1
- Menu item name 2

Restaurant name 3
- Menu item name 1
- Menu item name 2

Answer (score 0):

Do not separately query `Restaurant` class. You just need to query `Menu` class and use `include` on the `restaurant` pointer field. This will make sure you have all the menu items, and the complete restaurant details with the items.

You should write something like:

```
var myQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Menu"));
        myQuery.include("restaurant");

        var myCollection = [];


        myQuery.find({

        success: function(results){

            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i)
            {
                // This will get you the restaurant name
                var rest_name = results[i].get("restaurant").attributes.restaurant_name;

        if(!myCollection[rest_name])
        {
        // This is the first menu item encountered belonging to this restuarant


        // Instantiate the array
        myCollection[rest_name] = [];

        }
        else
        {
        // You have already encountered a menu item belonging to this restaurant before
        // Do nothing
        }
        myCollection[rest_name].push(results[i].get("menu_item_name"));




            }
// This will give you the arrays all filled up with data and you can show it in whatever way you want.

        }


        });
```

Edit: I have used an array of arrays to store the dynamic restaurant information.

Comment: You raise some good points. Yes, the number of restaurants aren't static, which is one of the pieces that I'm struggling with. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @MichaelSmith, One alternative is to use array of arrays. Please see my edit how I did it.